# Page not found (404) error django for given id in url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have this path :

```
re_path('likecomment/(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)/', LikeComment_view , name="LikeComment_page"),
```

and I have the fallowing view:

```
def LikeComment_view(request , comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment , id=comment_id)
    if not comment.liked.filter(id = request.user.id).exists():
        comment.likes += 1
        comment.liked.add(request.user)
        comment.save()
    else:
        comment.likes -= 1
        comment.liked.remove(request.user)
        comment.save()
```

and I generate the url with this code in template:

```
{% url 'LikeComment_page' i.id %}
```

and when I try to enter this url :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/likecomment/6/
```

I get an 404 error . I have the object with id=6 but I still get this error!

here is the models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True , blank=True)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post , on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True , blank=True)
body = models.TextField(help_text="comment text!" , max_length=1001)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0 , help_text="amount of likes")
liked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User , blank=True , related_name="liked")
```

Comment: Are you sure the `Comment` model uses `id` as its primary key field?  It's more common to use `pk` instead.  Please show us the `Comment` model definition.

Comment: This can be answered for `re_path`, but instead of giving options for what seems to me like unnecessary use, why not just use `path` for simplicity and no regex? For example: `from django.urls import include, path` and `path("like_comment/<int:comment_id>/", LikeComment_view, name="LikeComment_page")`

Comment: Unrelated to the core question, however, should the `if not comment.likes.filter(` code be `if not comment.liked.filter(`?  The `likes` attribute seems to be an int field to keep a count, not related field.

Comment: yes , I am sure that pk is id field. I added the model too

Comment: I tried using path but it did't work too